# the proper ways to aggregate two arrays into a single one with given shape

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision

There are two arrays of shape `[1, 255, 255, 1]`, I would like to aggregate them together into `[1,255, 255,2]`. What's the proper way to do it in numpy?

I am trying to use

```
import numpy as np
A = np.append(A1, A2)
```

But looks like it is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give us a harder one!

```
AA= np.concatenate((A1,A2), axis=-1)
```

since the 2 arrays match in the number of dimensions, and you want to join them on the last axis (`-1`), and the other dimensions match, just use `concatenate`.

In fact most of the array joining tasks can be done with concatenate.  Some may require adding dimensions. But here things already match.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What does axis=-1 mean, I try to google the explanation for assigning axis=-1, and get no answer.

Comment: In Python list indexing `-1` often means `last`; here it has the same meaning - last dimension.  If you think of the shape as a tuple, it's the last element of the tuple.  You could have used `axis=3`.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
A = np.append(A1, A2).reshape(1, 255, 255, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.